# hiding own Sqlite database from deompiling

Tags: android, sqlite, assets, decompiler

I want to write an android application that uses ready information I use Sqlite manager extension from Firefox and put it in asset folder but if someone just change the extension and make apk file a zip file he can easily have my database what is the best solution in this case?

Comment: the best solution is to avoid putting the database in the apk. but anyway, you need to consider that anything that goes on a user's phone can be compromised.

Comment: You can only make it harder. For example encrypt the database with AES.  Or move your db to the internet, and download it if needed, or direkty access it in the inet.

Comment: Anyway your DB will be accessible; you can just encrypt sensitive data

Answer (score 2):

The comments you are getting are all completely correct.  There is no way to guarantee that no-one can get at the contents of that database.

You could make it harder by encrypting the database and hiding the key somewhere in the code.  Doing that would make it so that an attacker would need to de-compile the code to find the key, so that they could de-crypt the DB.

Better yet, you could put the key on a network server, somewhere.  If you do that, your user has to be on-line to use the app... and the attacker has to spoof your app and request the key to decrypt the database.  ... but they can still do it.

This is the DRM problem.  It is pretty much impossible to give attackers the encrypted content and the keys and still protect the content.

Comment: Technically they don't have to decompile the app to get the key, they can just scrape it from memory of the running app.